# how to disable camera from browser using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, camera

Following is my code that i use to display CAM using HTML5 features, which is running fine i can snip a photo and easily see it in canvas. The problem is i dont know how to disable this camera feature. Let say i have snipped a picture now i want to do some other thing but camera still remains on with its flash light(those cameras/laptops that have flash light).

```
jQuery('#snap_upload').on('click', function() {
            jQuery('#camer_div').show();
            var video = document.querySelector("#vid");
            var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var onCameraFail = function(e) {
                console.log('Camera did not work.', e);
            };
            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                localMediaStream = stream;
            }, onCameraFail);

            jQuery('#take_picture').on('click', function() {
                if (localMediaStream) {
                    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: @Joe: Let me test that

Comment: @Joe: This is not triggering at all

Comment: @Joe: It works was browser issue i guess, Post it as answer if you want